# SQL Random Sample With Case When Statement (Teradata)

Tags: sql, random, case, teradata

I need to write a query that will return a random sample of records. But I must able to specify the sample size based on the value of one field.

This is a simplified version of the query I'm working on. In this example I need to return a total of 300 records, 100 where tier = 1 and 200 where tier =2.

I'm not sure if this is possible with the Sample feature.

```
 SELECT 
 ID,
 TIER

 FROM TIERTABLE a

 SAMPLE CASE WHEN TIER = 1 
 THEN 100
 WHEN TIER = 2
 THEN 200 END
```

Comment: What SQL engine?  Random methods vary per database.  You could order by random() if supported or newID or whatever random mechanism exists and select where tier = 1 with a top/limit of 100 and union where tier = 2 with a top/limit of 200

Answer (score 2):

You're close :-) Simply remove the `CASE`

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   TIER

FROM TIERTABLE a

SAMPLE
   WHEN TIER = 1 THEN 100
   WHEN TIER = 2 THEN 200
END
```

Comment: Dangit I was so close. This solution worked. Thanks for the help